# Does a new Windows 2019 domain controller require Windows to be activated before it will function as a logon server?

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller, activation

I have set up a new domain controller.  I believe I've done all the necessary things. DNS is synchronized, DHCP is transferred and working, and handing out the new server as DNS, also working. Is a global catalog role, all objects are synchronized, and FSMO roles are transferred.

However, domain members are refusing to use the new domain controller.  If I turn off the old domain controller, everything on the domain breaks, and no one can log on.

There is one thing I have not done.  I have not "activated windows" yet.  I was going to wait to do that after the new DC was working.

Is it necessary to activate Windows on a domain controller before it will authenticate users or servers?

Comment: No, Windows is fully functional without activation. Check replication, `repadmin /showreps`. Also check it is advertising all services `nltest /dsgetdc:domain.com /server:2019dcname`.

Comment: if you want to migrate, you need to transfer the fsmo roles, if its the only one

Comment: I already transferred the FSMO roles.  repadmin reports successes when run from either new DC or old DC.  nltest results are anomalous, in that if I run nltest /dsgetdc:domain.com /server:2019dcname , it reports on 2012dcname instead (with 2012dcname's IP address etc).

Comment: @GregAskew  about windows activation - if you've personally witnessed this, or have concrete documentation (copy or link), and put that as answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: There should be logs or an error message if you specifically tried to login to the new domain controller and it failed. Try reactivating the license evaluation period by running slmgr /rearm so that you can at least eliminate that as your concern.

Comment: If nltest reports the old machine when asking for the new one, triple check your DNS.